# Search for value and find value in next column

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a list of numbers which are associated with scores:

```
    Number   Score
    1        1
    2        2
    3        4
    4        7
    5        10
    6        15
```

I have these on their own sheet. Lets say cell A1 in another sheet has a value of 5, I'd like to look up 5 on this other sheet and return 10.  How would I do this?  I've found lots of functions such as CHOOSE and INDEX but no working examples.

Comment: This doesn't belong to Stackoverflow but rather to **WebApplications**.

Comment: I was worried about that as I posted it... is there an easy way to move it, or shall I delete or leave it?

Comment: Just leave it. Others will mark it closed or flag it for migration... If not let it be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) is your friend that will do exactly what you require.

In your case you'd use it as:

```
=vlookup(A1, Sheet2!A2:Sheet2!B7, 2)
```

But in your case if you're regularly using this mapping table I'd define it as a named range so it would be easier to use on other sheets. Changing data or resizing would still work without changing any references to it because you'd just change the named range.

Comment: It worked - got exactly what I was after first time with your help, thanks!

Comment: depending on whether you only want exact matches you might need to add a 4th argument to the VLOOKUP (FALSE)......